# Postmessage orgin and data undefined

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

I am trying to use postmessage to communicate between a parent window, and a child iframe, both of which are located on different domains.

For the parent window I have the code

```
var otherFrame = document.getElementById("otherFrame").contentWindow;
otherFrame.postMessage("sent'", "https://iframeURL.net");
```

For the child iframe I have the code

```
function receiveMessage(event){

    if (event.origin !== "https://parentURL.com")
        return;

    console.log((event.orgin + " " + event.message));
};

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

However, whenever the code is executed, the console logs both event.origin and event.message as undefined, even though the receiveMessage method is called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the origin was undefined, it wouldn't log the message....according to your code.

Comment: @Woody that's what makes it all the more confusing. It logs "undefined undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution to this was very dumb. I misspelled 'origin' in my code, and realized that the correct syntax is **event.data**, and not **event.message**